# how to select datas five by five in sql

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, sql

I want a forum-like page. Like bottom of the page i have page numbers

*1 2 3 .... 45 46 47 48*

I want to get 5 comments per page. So i should get comments (11-15)  when user clicks 3. page or comments (41-45) when 9. page choosen. how can i do this.

```
SELECT * FROM mytable //five by five
```

**Note** I think there should be an easy way in SQL commands.(like `ORDER BY something`  could work on my problem?)

but all answers(PHP, Javascript) are welcome.

Answer (score 2):

It's much more pseudo code than real SQL query:

```
SELECT * FROM comment LIMIT (5*{$page-1}),5;
```

Comment: is first given value to LIMIT (5*{$page-1}) describe where to start?

Comment: Yes, `(5*{$page-1})` is where to start (for page = 2, it's `5*1`), second number is how many records will be returned.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the sql limit clause.

```
SELECT * FROM comment LIMIT 0,5
```

The first parameter is where you want to start, the second one is the number or result.

So in your case :

```
SELECT * FROM comment LIMIT ((page_number-1)*5),5;
```

You can use your page links (1 2 3 ....) to pass the page number as a parameter.

```
<a href="comment.php?page=5">5</a>
```

And then retrieve it before doing you sql request.

```
$start = ($_GET['page'] - 1)*5;
$sql = "SELECT * FROM comment LIMIT $start,5";
```